# Complex EF data object written to DB in one SQL transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm looking at the rewrite of an ASP.NET application, from website / dataset techology to MVC / EF.  This question is about a particular function that I need to research.  I'm so new to EF that I don't know where to start. This question is about where to start.

The current application acts on complex data objects which I'll call XYZs.  An XYZ has a data structure something like this:
...Header (1)
.....Major Units (1 to several per header)
.........Minor Units (many per major unit)
............ Auxiliary Units (a few per minor unit)

The XYZs can be pulled from the DB into separate datasets which can then be serialized, encrypted and downloaded.  The downloaded XYZs can then be uploaded, decrypted, deserialized back to datasets and and then added to the DB as copies of the original (not replacements).

My general understanding is that in EF it is possible to create an object that is like an in-memory dataset structure, that could hold the entire imported XYZ and that could then be written to DB in one reversible SQL transaction (while maintaining parent-child key relationships among the new record IDs).

My question is, what are some names of EF objects and methods that I can use for starting points to learn about:
...the EF object that is equivalent to an in-memory dataset
...the EF function of writing that in-memory object to the DB in one reversible SQL transaction

Comment: This should be covered pretty well in EF tutorials. Basically, make a new EF model and include (check) these tables. EF will figure out the nested object structure. However, this will only work automatically if your database is designed with foreign keys. FYI, such questions are better served on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Happy to have someone move it to Stack Overflow.  Although I thought this was the place for more general questions, vs only very specific ones at SO.

Comment: I thought of SO, because the question is about how to use a specific technology.